# regex replace: how to indent a variable number of lines in the middle of the rest of the match

Tags: python, regex, vim, indentation

This is a question I have in terms of vim's regex, but a python regex would also be helpful and welcome. Let's take as an example this python function:

```
def func_hello (*args):
    for arg in args:
        print 'Hello, %s!' % arg
```

I want to turn this into a method in a class (not really - just in this example), with a method_hello method (I don't actually name things this way). I can do something like this:

```
:%s/def func_\(\w*\) (\(.*\)):\(\(\n\s\+.*\)\+\)/class \u\1 (object):\r\tmethod_\1 (self, \2):\r\t\3/g
```

However, that gives me this:

```
class Hello (object): 
    method_hello (self, arg1, arg2, arg3): 

    for arg in arg1, arg2, arg3: 
        print 'Hello, %s!' % arg
```

I was trying to make something like this work to gather multiple lines (which it does)

```
\(\(\n\s\+.*\)\+\)
```

...and then indent them all with this (which it doesn't)

```
\r\t\3
```

...because I don't know how to prepend each line in the match with tabs. I seem to need a regular expression inside my regular expression, to match a variable number of lines and prepend each with tabs.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No worries. I wouldn't do it in production code. This was more about things like hotkeys set up in my .vimrc to do wild things. I guess the core of the question - what I really wanted to know - is whether or not regex patterns can nest like this.

Comment: Strictly **regular** expressions can't - they are provably incapable of handling nested structures of arbitrary depth.  If you allow backreferences in search patterns, then the regex isn't really regular anymore and you have a chance - but this isn't a good use of regex.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do it with regex.  But if the goal is to have shortcut in Vim, then here is what you want:

`nmap <yourkey> vip>Oclass Hello(object):<esc>+f(aself, <esc>`

Or something along these lines.  In most cases I've met, in vim it's easier to define hotkey in terms of other hotkeys.